# Real-time impulse response convolution with FFTW -- result sounds like IR is symmetrical

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, convolution, fftw

For research purposes I am building a real-time reverb convolution engine in C++ using FFTW (and PortAudio for the sound delivery) with the overlap-add method for convolution. Most of it is working, but a very peculiar effect occurs. Though I can't see why, it sounds very much as if the impulse response becomes symmetrical: what was `h[n]` becomes `h[n] + h[-n]`. Does anyone know if performing FFT in the way I describe below would have this effect?

Basically, my process is as follows:

#### Known in advance:

- `h`, an impulse response `m` samples long
- `x`, a sound `n` samples long
- `FFT_SIZE`, a partition size/window size

`n > m` by a factor of 3 ish but `FFT_SIZE` is much smaller (1024 at the moment)

#### Work done in an offline phase before audio starts:

I split `x` into portions of `FFT_SIZE` length. Because I will convolve each window with `h`, I copy each one into a 0-padded buffer of length `n+m - 1` samples, and perform a forward FFT, saving the resulting complex array. (I have `n/FFT_SIZE` complex arrays.) For now I am using rectangular windowing with no overlap, will implement Hamming if it improves things once I resolve this issue.

I furthermore perform a single forward FFT of `h` after 0-padding to length `n+m - 1`, and store this single complex array of same size as the others.

#### During the real time phase

PortAudio like most audio engines invokes callbacks to fill a buffer `out` with sound data at regular intervals. In my callback (which by design requests `FFT_SIZE` samples of audio, I select the complex array representing the next window each time (since one callback invocation corresponds to same sound length as one window for FFT).

I perform pointwise multiplication of this array with the one I made by FFT-ing `h`, and perform IFFT. Resulting sound buffer is `n+m-1` long, much bigger than `FFT_SIZE`, so I copy only the beginning into the `out` buffer and add the rest to a overlap/carry buffer (which accumulates reverb tail sound with each callback invocation) after moving the beginning of the carry buffer to `out` (so `out` now contains one window's worth of new IFFT'd data added to one window's worth of previously calculated decay tail).

### The concern now

Like I mentioned before, it sounds like somehow the impulse response is not being FFT'd correctly, and is resulting in behaving as if it was symmetrical -- reversed and then added to itself. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't see how this effect can be produced by a problem with my carrying -- though if I am, i'd be glad to have found the bug!

My best guess is that somehow I'm supposed to perform windowing of `h`as well. However, based on the literature I've read, you just convolve each window of `x` with the whole `h` and do the carry. Is this wrong perhaps?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember that you can analyze your problem in the Fourier domain as well. If the impulse response appears to be `h[n] + h[-n]` in the time domain, it's `H(f) + H(-f)` in the frequency domain as well. Windowing would **not** behave similar to that, nor fix it.

Comment: you zero-pad h to matching length; now, h is real-valued, if I understand you correctly; hence, you're probably using one of FFTW's real2complex transforms? Are you sure you're using the full, symmetric DFT, instead of just one half?

Comment: Are you doing your pointwise multiplication using complex arithmetic?

Comment: Hello all, thanks for questions. In order: @MSalters I mean to say that the sound I hear is what I would expect from `h` being symmetrical,; upon investigation of the actual float array containing `h` it is not, and looks correct

Comment: @MarcusMüller `h` is real-valued, I am therefore using fftwf_make_plan_r2c_1d(..). How do you mean "full, symmetric DFT"? I was believing that if you output with complex data rather than in-place, the negative-frequency part of the output is dropped on account of it being identical?

Comment: @hotpaw2 My pointwise multiplication takes two same-length arrays of complex numbers and outputs another of same length, where each complex number in out has real component = product of the two reals and imaginary component = product of the two imaginaries that are found at that index in each of the input arrays

Comment: @Quintana: see http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT.html#The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT ; the negative frequency part shouldn't be identical, but complex conjugate.

Comment: @Quintana, by the way, you can use this as reference implementation:  [GNU Radio FFT filters with real input (f), real output (f) and real-valued taps(f): `fft_filter_fff`](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-filter/lib/fft_filter_fff_impl.cc), where the interesting part is done by an FFTW plan [just like yours](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-fft/lib/fft.cc#L237). However, see how [in the `filter` method](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-filter/lib/fft_filter.cc#L167) the matching r2c inverse transform is used.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for those references. They will certainly be helpful (though hotpaw2's answer ended up solving my current problem). Also thanks for pointing out the detail of complex conjugate; I should have said "symmetrical" there rather than "identical" though even that is less precise.

Comment: @Quintana "symmetrical, but one side is complex conjugate" = "hermitian" :) 

by the way, much of your problem fits well on dsp.stackexchange.com, where you can use formulas more easily in your questions, too!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did see several questions answered at dsp site, and considered posting there. and thanks for clarifying~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arithmetic when point-wise multiplying the 2 FFT vectors appears to be wrong. Complex vector multiplication has to take into account the cross product between the real and imaginary components. e.g. re = re1*re2 - im1*im2; im = re1*im2 + re2*im1 , etc.

Comment: there we go, problem solved. i was scouring my algorithm logic, as it were, and not my multiplication function!

Comment: Note that `std::complex` has a proper `std::operator*`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for pointing that out; at the moment I have compiled FFTW to output its data as `float[2]` rather than `std::complex` (i am told that you can do a direct cast but as my code is currently written I would have to do some refactoring to swing that)