# Calculating correlation with FFT between two signals

Tags: c++, c, fft

I am having a problem getting a correct result for a correlation between two sets of values (I know the results are wrong because I've tried calculating the correlation in Octave)(also I'm calculating like the [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar) says).
I've been using a library I found that's written in C  that's found on: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html

The documentation for it is rather scarce and I don't have much experience in calculating FFT.

An example of the program's results and the results from Octave are following:

The two vectors are:
a = [1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0], b = [0 0 0 0 1 3 1 1]

the results for fft of the vector a and b on Octave are:

[image: fft-octave]

While the results of fft of the same vectors are (divided into real and imaginary numbers):

[image: result from C lib function]

The output of the function is originally:

5
-1
1.70711
3.12132
0
1
0.292893
1.12132

(the division into real and imaginary numbers was done how it was specified in the documentation)

[image]

Now my problem starts when i multiply (I'm using element-wise multiplication) the two vectors that contain results from the DFT (I'm using Real DFT) since the results from Octave are different than the result of my program

[image: Octave result]

my multiplication code is:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[j] = a[j] * b[j];
}
```

and the result is:

[image: multiplication of output of rdft function from lib]

[image: formatted result]

This is the point where I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to multiply by the **complex conjugate** of the FFT of `b` - otherwise you're performing convolution rather than cross-correlation - see [this example on DSP.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12630/cross-correlation-with-fft-and-fftshift).

Comment: Hey @PaulR thank you for the comment. Before I started implementing the complex conjugate like you suggested I performed convolution between the FFT of the two vectors and I got a different result than the one my program returned.

Comment: Also is it possible that the issue is because the output of the FFT contains only half of the entire FFT?

Comment: Note that different FFT implementations may use different scale factors (e.g. 1, 1/N, 1/sqrt(N)), and if you're using a real-to-complex FFT in you're C code then you'll need to take care of the other half of the spectrum.

Comment: well the Real DFT and it's usage is described in [here](http://prntscr.com/a7q7wt) 
and the output looks like it's only half of the size of the original vector

Comment: Not quite a dup.  But a suitable answer to a related question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760137/real-time-impulse-response-convolution-with-fftw-result-sounds-like-ir-is-sym/34775275#34775275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue resides with ... drumrolls... the multiplication (as you've already guessed given your "my problem starts when I multiply" statement)!

Convolution in the time domain (with sufficient zero padding) is equivalent in the frequency domain to a *complex* multiplication of the spectrums. In Octave that's what the `*` operator does. With an array of `float` or `double` in C or C++, the `*` operator only multiplies the real or imaginary part together.

To multiply the spectrum's complex numbers, accounting for the indicated data packing order, you may instead use:

```
a[0] = a[0] * b[0]; // a[0] corresponds to real-valued bin 0
a[1] = a[1] * b[1]; // a[1] corresponds to real-valued bin n/2
for (j = 1; j < n/2; j++) {
    tmp      = (a[2*j]*b[2*j]   - a[2*j+1]*b[2*j+1]); // real-part
    a[2*j+1] = (a[2*j]*b[2*j+1] + a[2*j+1]*b[2*j]);   // imaginary-part
    a[2*j]   = tmp;
}
```

**Notes**:

- The [C FFT implementation](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html) takes a real-valued input and only return the non-redundant lower half of the frequency spectrum (the upper half can be obtained by symmetry). The inverse transform would correspondingly take the non-redundant lower half of the spectrum and compute the corresponding real-valued sequence (so only handling half the spectrum is not the issue in this case).
- Also, as you may have noticed, the [C FFT implementation](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html) you've used is based on a different definition of the DFT (which uses an exponent with a positive argument) than Octave. It is not an issue so long as you also use a consistent inverse transform (ie. one where the exponent has a negative argument). For comparison purposes your results with the [C FFT implementation](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html) correspond to the complex conjugate of the results from Octave.

Comment: Sadly i forgot to update it but I have already fixed the multiplication of complex numbers ... right now it's working fairly properly .. the only issue I'm having is when using reverse FFT, the results are only correct if I would be rounding the numbers

Comment: Then you should be able to tell whether this post addresses the problem you described in your question. If so, you could consider marking the answer as accepted for future readers' benefits. Regarding your remaining reverse FFT issue, you could add the details to a new question, and we'll happily look at it.